# video player mobile - a way to represent two different sources

Tags: mobile-application, video

I've implemented two protocols to provide video on demand in my app. The first one is optimised for slow connections and the other one for better video quality. How to provide a way to let users switch to other protocol if they are experiencing viewing troubles?

I thought of a button, just like some players do for their Standard/High definition switch, but it's not exactly the case here and I don't want to reveal the name of two protocols. At this moment the player is used on both Android and iOS and takes full width at portrait and relatively height with about one real finger height cell below, which contains some info for the video.

Comment: Why is a Standard/High switch "not exactly the case"?

Comment: because the one protocol based on your network speed can change video quality, but there one case that video changes quality too much and becomes uncomfortable for the user and the other has a medium quality but fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users won't know/care about which protocols are used - they just want the video to work. Your goal is to give them an option if it's not working well. You don't have to tell them anything about "how" it works.

Consider what options you could offer:

- Resolution (like YouTube). This assumes people understand
  "480p/720p/1080p". Many don't.
- Connection speed. More work to detect connection type and adjust automatically, but no button necessary. Asking people to choose 3G/LTE/Wi-Fi assumes they know.
- SD/HD. Don't assume people know what this means either. Someone might think it means save the video on an SD card - who knows.
- "HD on/off" (like Vimeo). Better, but still requires knowing what "HD" means.
- A simple button for "Video Quality: Standard/High." No jargon, easy to understand.

Comment: I marked your answer as correct because made me think on right way. Sometimes if you don't present something well means you made some bad decision.